# accessing nested json (prepared by gson) using jquery inside a map

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, gson

I have a java object like that has a couple of object fields which have basic fields in them, here is an example:

```
Template {
    String name;
    EmailMessage defaultEmailMessage;
}
EmailMessage {
    String emailSubject;
    String emailBody;
}
```

I have a spring controller method that returns a list of templates in json format using gson.

In my jsp I use a jquery ajax call to get this list and then populate some html content based on it, here is a shortened version:

```
$.ajax({
    type : "GET",
    url : '<c:url value="/listTemplates.htm"/>',
    dataType: 'json',
    success : function(templates) {
    var map = $.map(templates, function(template) { 
        return { 
            "name": template.name,
            "emailSubject": template.defaultEmailMessage.emailSubject
    };});
        $("#thumbnails-ul").html($("#campaignThumbTmpl").tmpl(map));
    },
    error : function(data) {
        alert(data.responseText);
    }
});
```

In firebug I see an error `undefined template.defaultEmailMessage` but when I debug I can evaulate both `template.defaultEmailMessage` and `template.defaultEmailMessage.emailSubject`. I tried using `$.each` but same problem. How can I access nested json? If you want to see the full output of json in the browser, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your  `"emailSubject": template.defaultEmailMessage.emailSubject` with `"emailSubject": template.defaultEmailMessage`

**ADDED LATER:**
 Why do you want to convert the data into json again ? you are requesting the data as json and again you are returning the json data into the template for compilation.Put the data directly into the template.

```
$.ajax({
          type:"GET",
          url:"<c:url value="/listTemplates.htm"/>",
          datatype:"application/json",
          success:function(templates){      
                   $.get("Put Your Template URL HERE",function(template}
                   var result = _.template(template);                                $("#thumbnails-ul").html($("#campaignThumbTmpl").tmpl(templates));
        });
             }
    });
```

This way you will be able to put the data wherever you want in your template by accessing it through `.each` loop as below:

```
 <% _.each(data,function(anynamehere){ %>
        <li><a href="<%= anynamehere.name %>"></li>
    <% }); %>
```

The above is a sample to print your name from the class but with other .each loop you can put other properties too....hope this helped...

Comment: that won't work. i am not converting data to json twice, not sure if I understand your question.

Comment: @Is7aq:check my answer now...!!

Comment: I see, I removed the code where json is rewritten, and instead I am passing the original json. but that does not solve my nested json problem, because inside template you cannot access nested json..

Comment: ur example only shows one level, i want to do something like this `anynamehere.message.subject`

Comment: Just use .each loop and you are done with it...nested json can be handled almost anywhere...

Comment: `.each` is not appropriate for my needs. I need access by name.